# how to disable truetype fonts in xterm?

Tags: xterm

When Xterm starting, true type fonts enabled by default. I have to disable them everytime in xterm menu bar. Maybe there's some parameter for .Xdefaults to disable them permenantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual, the following should work (in `.Xdefaults`):

```
XTerm*vt100.renderFont: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
xterm.vt100.renderFont: false
```

to my .Xresources file in my home directory and it stopped the true type fonts.